# NOT EXIST in SQL

Tags: sql, not-exists

Can someone help me in understanding how we get the below result for the query

```
Select RECIPIENTNAME from donations A
where not exists
                ((SELECT DONORORGANIZATION
                  from donations
                  where RECIPIENTNAME = 'Chambell')
                 MINUS
                (SELECT DONORORGANIZATION
                 from donations B
                 where B.RECIPIENTNAME =A.RECIPIENTNAME ));
```

The data is

```
Chambell   A
Chambell   B
John       A
John       B
```

To my understanding, the inner subquery is not empty so it should return FALSE to non exist and hence no tuples should come in the result.

Where am i going wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Why is empy the inner subquery? BTW, is this oracle?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
Select RECIPIENTNAME
from donations A
where not exists ((select DONORORGANIZATION
                   from donations
                   where RECIPIENTNAME = 'Chambell'
                  ) MINUS
                  (select DONORORGANIZATION
                   from donations B
                   where B.RECIPIENTNAME = A.RECIPIENTNAME
                  )
                 );
```

The subquery gets all organizations that "Chambell" is in that the outer recipient is not in.  This is empty if the recipient is in all organizations with "Chambell".  Clearly, "Chambell" matches this condition.  As does anyone else who is in all organizations with "Chambell".

Note this doesn't return your exact output, because this only returns one column.